OpenSSL errors, dropping connections
We have four Windows Server 2016 servers that are exactly the same, hardware and software.
These servers are running a homegrown message queue.  Each server maintains 2000 connections to offsite servers.
Recently we upgraded our software from OpenSSL 1.1 to OpenSSL 3.0.8.  3 times now in the past 2 weeks on only one of these servers we have seen it slowly dropping those connections.  This happens only one server, the other 3 haven't had this issue.  Connections continually drop until we restart the application.
When we look at our application logs we see that the server has a forcible disconnect message.  When we look at the disconnect clients we see the following errors from OpenSSL:
10/09 05:19:30|SSL3 alert read:fatal:internal error, File:TaCFdcSSLSocket.cpp, Ln:548
10/09 05:19:30|SSL_connect:Error in error, File:TaCFdcSSLSocket.cpp, Ln:553
10/09 05:19:30|Unknown error, RemoteHost: svrp000ae4aa StatusCode = 183, File:TaCFdcSSLSocket.cpp, Ln:1174
10/09 05:19:30| 1 SSL_connect failed with error Remotehost: svrp000ae4aa.60020000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80, File:TaCFdcSSLSocket.cpp, Ln:1191
10/09 05:19:30|The TLS/SSL connect failed. ErrorCode = 1, File:TaCFdcSSLSocket.cpp, Ln:330

I don't know if anyone can shed some light on this but any suggestions/help is appreciated.
